# Installing a outdoor light timer

Tags: electrical

I got it working but man it's messed up. Here is the situation: Crude Diagram attached. This seems to be working. [image]

The switch on the left is tied to another switch in my kitchen for the front foyer hallway. This switch only works if I tie the white wire from the source (bottom) to a black wire from either the source (right bottom or right top).

If I connect the white wire from the Leviton white wire (common) to the other white wires the timer won't work. If I tie the white wire from the source (bottom left) to anything else (including the other white commons) the hallway switch wont work.

If I attached the white wire from the source (bottom left) to the black wire of the Leviton Timer Switch both switches "work" but when I turn on the timer switch to give power to the outside lights it flickers (I hear the relay clicking) about 4 times per second.

Anyone explain/help?

Comment: How did you identify which cable is the source?

Comment: I can't view most of the drawing on my phone but some of the connections look sketchy.

Comment: Can you take/post a photo of the inside of the box and give us the model of the timer switch?  (Also, I suspect bottom right is the source based on your diagram.)